# DefaultBufferMaxRows is not changing in ssis

Tags: ssis

Can any one tell,what is the reason the DefaultBufferMaxRows is automaticaly changing to 10000 when i run the package through BIDS.My package contains only one source,lookup,destination tasks.total 100000 records i want to insert into destination table by doing lookup to same destination table(non matched record).total 5 columns are passing,all are the type of int.
Actually i have increased the DefaultBufferMaxRows to 50000 before running the package and all other settings are default.What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultBufferMaxRows and DefaultBufferSize work together as a limit. DefaultBufferMaxRows is set to 10,000 rows by default; DefaultBufferSize is set to 10MB by default. If the rows are 1k in size, the property settings are roughly equivalent. For rows larger than 1k, the DefaultBufferSize limit will be reached first. For rows smaller than 1k, the DefaultBufferMaxRows limit will be reached first. Since these properties work in tandem, you need to adjust *both* properties to change the number of rows (or size) of the buffer in an SSIS Data Flow Task.

Hope this helps,
Andy

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply.So,If i want to push 50000 records into buffer in one shot,what are the changes i have to make?

Comment: You are likely already setting the DefaultBufferMaxRows property to 50000. If you are not seeing more than 10,000 rows in each buffer, you should set the DefaultBufferSize to something like 52428800 (5 * 10485760, or roughly 50M).